# Understanding why this python code works randomly

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm coding a little script that gets metadata from a sound file and creates a string with the desired values. I know I'm  doing something wrong but I ain't sure why, but it's probably the way I am iterating the if's. When I run the code :

```
import os, mutagen

XPATH= "/home/xavier/Code/autotube/tree/def"

DPATH="/home/xavier/Code/autotube/tree/down"


def get_meta():
    for dirpath, directories,files in os.walk(XPATH):
        for sound_file in files :
            if sound_file.endswith('.flac'):
                from mutagen.flac import FLAC
                metadata = mutagen.flac.Open(os.path.join(dirpath,sound_file))
                for (key, value) in metadata.items():
                    #print (key,value)
                    if key.startswith('date'):
                        date = value
                        print(date[0])

                    if key.startswith('artist'):
                        artist = value
                        #print(artist[0])
                    if key.startswith('album'):
                        album = value
                        #print(album[0])
                    if key.startswith('title'):
                        title = value
                        #print(title[0])
                        build_name(artist,album,title)  # UnboundLocalError gets raised here


def build_name(artist,album,title):
    print(artist[0],album[0],title[0])
```

I get the desired result or an error, randomly :

RESULT :

```
1967 Ravi Shankar & Yehudi Menuhin West Meets East Raga: Puriya Kalyan
```

ERROR :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 39, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 31, in get_meta
    build_name(artist,album,title)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'album' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: add `album=""` before `for` loop

Comment: If you look at the `if` blocks in your `for` loops, some iterations will assign `album`; some try and use `album`. If the conditions that lead to trying to use `album` occur before the conditions that lead to assigning `album`, then you are trying to use an unassigned variable.

Comment: Since you don't have `import random` I would be surprised if your code works *randomly* although it might work *unexpectedly*

Comment: [Ravi Shankar & Yehudi Menuhin West Meets East Raga: Puriya Kalyan](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pouL822FXJ0) (c:

Comment: @PeterWood Hey it is on youtube :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If `"title"` comes before `"album"` in the meta data then `album` will never be initialised. `"album"` may not exist at all.

As you don't blank out the value of `album` for each track, if a track has previously had `"album"` defined then the next track which doesn't define `"album"` will use the previous track's value.

Give it a blank value for each track (if that's reasonable to you).

Looking at `build_name` the values are lists of strings, so the default should be `['']`:

```
for sound_file in files:
    artist = album = title = ['']
```

However, you will still not get values before calling `build_name` if the metadata is out of order.

You need to move `build_name(artist, album, title)` out of the loop:

```
for (key, value) in metadata.items():
    ...  # searching metadata
build_name(artist, album, title)
```

Comment: Emptying the variables at the beggining of the loop worked, but now I am getting random results on the string : `:w !python3
['1967']   ['Raga: Puriya Kalyan']
['1967']   ['Swara-Kakali']
['1967']   ['Prabhati']
['1967']   ['Sonata N°3 in a minor, op 25']
` You can't probably see correctly here, but it is giving only two fields instead of 4, sometimes the all 4 fields, sometimes 3, randomly

Comment: @xavier You also need to change the indentation of "build_name(artist,album,title)" by getting rid of 2 indents. Dictionaries in Python don't necessarily get iterated in a repeatable order. This means that the metadata key "title" isn't always last. Changing the indentation means that the artist, album, and title will be properly loaded BEFORE build_name() gets called.

Comment: I am having problems with my configuration on Vim and the indentation ... I have to take a look at it cause it could cause me severe brain damage on the long run ... thank you for your help !

Comment: @xavier, as a general rule of thumb: parse first, interpret later